# Titles overlapping or going out

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to have 4 plots with a title for each of them and a main title.
I first tried this code :

```
set.seed(13);  
par(mfrow = c(2,2))  
for(i in 1:4){  
  plot(runif(10), t = "l", lwd = 3)  
  title(main='I have a title for each of the plots') 
}  
title(main="This is a very long title which needs to fit on two lines.\nUnfortunately it overlaps the other titles and it's not readible", outer=TRUE, line=-2)
```

[image]

I tried making the main title go higher or lower but either it goes out of the screen or overlaps the other titles.

Having larger plots don't help either...

Does anyone have any idea how to sort this out?

Comment: use `par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0,0,2,0))` and `line = -1` looks fine to me

Comment: That did the trick thanks! What do the parameters for `oma` represent?

Comment: `o`uter `m`argin `a`rea = `c(bottom, left, top, right)` margin spacing

Comment: @rawr, why not make that on official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting @rawr's answer here to close out the question

```
set.seed(13);  
par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0,0,2,0))
for(i in 1:4){  
  plot(runif(10), t = "l", lwd = 3)  
  title(main='I have a title for each of the plots') 
}  
title(main=paste0("This is a very long title which needs to fit on two lines.\n",
     "Unfortunately it overlaps the other titles and it's not readable"), 
      outer=TRUE, line=-1)
```

The trick was to increase the **o**uter **m**margin **a**rea (`oma=c(bottom, left, top, right)`) to put more space at the top of the image to have room for the text. And also to move the title up a bit more.

[image: resulting image]